# the proof of some identities related to modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I want to prove the identities below, could anyone give me a hint please?

> If $A$ is a module with additive identity element $0_A$ over a ring $R$ with additive identity $0_R$, then it is easy to show that for all $r\in R,a\in A$:
>   $$r0_A=0_A\quad\text{and}\quad0_Ra=0_A.$$
>   In the sequel $0_A,0_R,0\in\Bbb Z$ and the trivial module $\{0\}$ will all be denoted 0.
>   It also is easy to verify that for all $r\in R,n\in\Bbb Z$ and $a\in A$:
>   $$(-r)a=-(ra)=r(-a)\quad\text{and}\quad n(ra)=r(na),$$
>   where $na$ has its usual meaning for groups (Definition I.1.8, additive notation).

Comment: Downvote for posting images of text. It was discussed countless times that images of text should not be posted because it makes it impossible to find the question using the search feature.

Comment: The answer also is given in this file https://orion.math.iastate.edu/maddux/505-Spring-2010/hw04.2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $r\,0_A=0_A$: in $\;r\,0_A=r(0_A+0_A)$, use distributivity and the cancellation law in groups. Similarly for $\;0_R\,a=0_A$.
- $(-r)a=-(ra)$: distributivity again: calculate $\;ra+(-r)a$.
- $n(ra)=r(na)$: induction and distributivity.

Comment: third one is not clear for me, could you give me more details? where willI use distributivity?

Comment: In the inductive step, you have use  distributivity first to expand $(n+1)ra$, then, after you've used the inductive hypothesis, to factor $r$.